# How would I define move constructor and move assignment operator for unique_ptr of custom data type?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, move, smart-pointers

```
class threadMsg_t {
private:
    string msg;
    int type;
public:
    threadMsg_t(const string& msg, int type) : msg(msg), type(type) {};
    threadMsg_t& operator=(threadMsg_t&& oldMsg)
    {
        msg = move(oldMsg.msg);
        type = move(oldMsg.type);
        return *this;
    }
    threadMsg_t(threadMsg_t&& oldMsg) {
        msg = move(oldMsg.msg);
        type = move(oldMsg.type);
    }
    int getType() { return type; }
    string getMsg() { return msg; }
};

using msgP_t = unique_ptr<threadMsg_t>;
static queue<msgP_t> q;
static condition_variable cv;
static mutex mtx;

static void postMsg(threadMsg_t* newMsg)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    q.push(std::move(msgP_t{newMsg}));
    cv.notify_one();
}

class workerThread_t {
public:
    static void processMsg()
    {
        while(true)  {
            unique_lock<mutex> lck{mtx};
            if(q.empty()) {
                cout << "Waiting for the message!" << endl;
                cv.wait(lck, []() { return !(q).empty(); });
            }
            if(q.empty()) {
                continue;
            }
            auto msgP = move(q.front());
            threadMsg_t* msg = msgP.get();
            q.pop();
            cout << "Processed Message - " << msg->getMsg() << endl;
            lck.unlock();
        }
    }
    thread* getThread()
    {
        return m_workerThread;
    }
    workerThread_t() {
        m_workerThread = new thread(&processMsg);
    }
    ~workerThread_t()
    {
        delete(m_workerThread);
    }
private:
    thread* m_workerThread;
};
```

Code works fine. But wondering the behavior when I do move(unique_ptr object) inside postMsg(). Seems like its not invoking the move constructor defined. Not sure whether its possible to define constructor for unique_ptr. I know that its needed for a custom structure containing "string" and "int". How would it behave if I have a ptr inside the structure?

Comment: When you move-construct `unique_ptr`, that just transfers the ownership of the underlying raw pointer from the source smart pointer to the destination. It doesn't copy or move the actual object those pointers point to. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Yes, I understand. Could you tell me the reason why I get this warning?
   `moving a temporary object prevents copy elision`. Getting this warning on `q.push(std::move(msgP_t{newMsg}));` in postMsg().

Comment: There's no point in applying `std::move` to a temporary, and in some cases it may in fact preclude optimizations. `msgP_t{newMsg}` is a temporary, and is already eligible to move from. Make it `q.push(msgP_t{newMsg})` or `q.emplace(newMsg)`. Better still, have `postMsg` take `msgP_t` as a parameter, to make it clear to callers that the function takes ownership of the object.